# WSO2 Identity Server dashboard behind reverse proxy redirects to wrong port on login

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have a WSO2 Identity Server behind a reverse apache proxy. The proxy listens on port 443 and the IS on port 9443.

I can see the dashboard (https://myhost/dashboard/) but as soon as I click 'Login' I am redirected to the wrong port (https://myhost:9443/samlsso )

I followed all the relevant instructions about putting the IS behind a proxy but it does not work.

In my apache config I have:

```
 ProxyPass / https://localhost:9443/
 ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:9443/
 SSLProxyEngine on
```

In my `repository/conf/carbon.xml` I have set `<HostName>` and `<MgtHostName>` to the name of the proxy.

In `repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml` I've added `proxyPort` and `proxyName` to the `Connector`.

Is there something else which needs to be configured?

**Update:**

I grepped for `9443/samlsso` and changed those occurrences in the configuration files but it did not solve my problem. I am still redirected to port 9443.

Then I grepped for `9443` and found ~80 occurrences in the configuration files. I find it hard to believe the proper way of configuring a simple port change is to change all those 80 occurrences.

Comment: Hi, have you resolved this issue? if so - can you tell me how?

Comment: @ChananBerler: I dug up my notes and added what we did as an answer to this question,

Answer (score 1):

Since people are still interested in this I dug up my notes on this and share the solution we had. It kind-of worked but I'm not sure if it is the proper solution and its not perfect but should get you started.

(We gave up on WSO2 stuff because of these and other problems)

So what we did for version 5.0.0 was:

- change `{{ site }}` into `localhost:9443` in :

  - `identity.xml`
  - `security/authenticators.xml`
  - `security/sso-idp-config.xml`
  - (and probably also in `account-recovery-gadget.xml` and `dashboard-index.jag`)
- add the property `proxyPort="443"` to the connector for port 9443 in `tomcat/catalina-server.xml`
- change the function `getServerUrl()` in `deployment/server/jagerryapps/dashboard/util/utility.jag` into `return "https://localhost:9443/services";`
- change `var postUrl = ...` into `var postUrl = 'https://{{ site }}/samlsso';` in `samlsso.jag`

Comment: Hi again, 
Thanks for the quick answer. Can I ask which solution did you use instead? is it still open source?

Comment: @ChananBerler: We changed the requirements of our app :). Anyway if we have to use WSO2 stuff, we use commercial support, they could set it up in a few hours where I spend days on figuring it out. So it seems information on how to do it is available. As for the future I'm considering using keycloak or CAS, I haven't decided yet.